# gap characters corresponding to the missing residues in a protein sequence using biopython

Tags: biopython, pdb

I have extracted sequence from pdb without missing residues but i need to have a sequence that has gaps (dash character) replacing missing residues. how can i do it?

thank you

Comment: Can you add a sample pdb sequence and the expected output sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually by parsing ATOM records of pdb to get existing residues and by parsing REMARK 465 to get missing residues:

```
pname = '4g5j.pdb' #downloaded file from PDB

fin = open(pname,'r')
content = fin.readlines()
fin.close()

res = []
mis_res = []

print('CHAIN A will be used for ALIGNMENT')
het_chain = 'A'

for i,line in enumerate(content):

  if line[0:4] == 'ATOM':

    split = [line[:6], line[6:11], line[12:16], line[17:20], line[21], line[22:26], line[30:38], line[38:46], line[46:54]]

    if split[4] != het_chain:
      continue
    res.append(int(split[5]))

for i,line in enumerate(content):

  if line[0:10] == 'REMARK 465':

    split = [line[:10], line[19], line[21:26]]

    if split[1] == het_chain:

      mis_res.append(int(split[2]))

resindexes = sorted(list(set(sorted(res))))

missed_resindexes = sorted(list(set(mis_res)))
missed_resindexes = [el for el in missed_resindexes if el not in resindexes]

all_indexes = sorted(resindexes+missed_resindexes)
print(len(all_indexes))

#here you should have your real sequence!
real_seq = 'GSMGEAPNQALLRILKETEFKKIKVLGSGAFGTVYKGLWIPEGEKVKIPVAIKELREATSPKANKEILDEAYVMASVDNPHVCRLLGICLTSTVQLITQLMPFGCLLDYVREHKDNIGSQYLLNWCVQIAKGMNYLEDRRLVHRDLAARNVLVKTPQHVKITDFGLAKLLGAEEKEYHAEGGKVPIKWMALESILHRIYTHQSDVWSYGVTVWELMTFGSKPYDGIPASEISSILEKGERLPQPPICTIDVYMIMVKCWMIDADSRPKFRELIIEFSKMARDPQRYLVIQGDERMHLPSPTDSNFYRALMDEEDMDDVVDADEYLIPQQG'

missed_seq = real_seq[:]

for i,el in enumerate(real_seq):
  if all_indexes[i] in missed_resindexes:
    print(i)
    missed_seq = missed_seq[:i]+'-'+missed_seq[i+1:]

print(missed_seq)
```

OUTPUT:
---GEAPNQALLRILKETEFKKIKVLGS----TVYKGLWIPEGEKVKIPVAIKE----------KEILDEAYVMASVDNPHVCRLLGICLTSTVQLITQLMPFGCLLDYVREHKDNIGSQYLLNWCVQIAKGMNYLEDRRLVHRDLAARNVLVKTPQHVKITDFGLAKLLGAEEKEYHAEGGKVPIKWMALESILHRIYTHQSDVWSYGVTVWELMTFGSKPYDGIPASEISSILEKGERLPQPPICTIDVYMIMVKCWMIDADSRPKFRELIIEFSKMARDPQRYLVIQGDERMHLPSPTDSNFYRALMDEEDMDDVVDADEY------

Comment: I checked it for 38 proteins, and about 20 times this script was successful. But sometimes amino acids appear under HEATATM records, so there will be error. Now i'm trying to use ProDy module to do this job.

Comment: The Biopython package can now parse REMARK 465 to get the missing residues using `parse_pdb_header()`, see [here](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1237) with use of it demonstrated [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fomightez/cl_demo-binder/blob/master/notebooks/Using%20Biopython%20PDB%20Header%20Parser%20to%20get%20missing%20residues.ipynb).